# Optimizing a Recursive Padovan (i.e. Fibonacci with dying rabbits) Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, optimization, fibonacci

I am a bit of a novice when it comes to Python (I just started learning it two weeks ago) but am having a lot of fun completing challenges. One challenge that is giving me trouble is a variation on the Fibonacci sequence with mortal rabbits (i.e. the Padovan sequence, but with variable lifespan).

After much trial and error, I have written a code that returns outputs that match with the tables I've made for different lifespan settings. However, the algorithm gets really slow at around 40 turns and for lifespans over 15 months, and the challenges are timed. The code I made is:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)



def fibd(n, m):
    if n < (m+2) and m > 3:
        return fib(n)
    elif n < (m+1) and m == 3:
        return fib(n)
    elif n >= (m+1) and m==3:
        return fibd(n-2, m) + fibd(n-3, m)
    elif n >= (m+2) and m > 3:
        return sum(map(fibd, [n-(m+x) for x in (range(-(m-2), 2))], [m]*m))
```

That's as simple as I could make it with my modest skillset, but I'm at a loss. n represents the number of turns where we stop counting, and m represents the number of turns each rabbit lives before dying. Basically, the first function gives the Fibonacci sequence. This is used because until the rabbits actually die, the Padovan generalization is identical to a Fibonacci sequence, so I need to call back to it as part of the recursion. Then, there is a separate chunk of code for a lifespan of 3, because while for lifespans of 4 or more, the formula for obtaining the number of rabbits on the nth turn is (n-2)+(n-3)...(n-(m+1)), with a lifespan of 3, the formula is different (it's just (n-2)+(n-3). The next chunk of code is for lifespans of 4 or greater.

Any input would be appreciated, even some hints if you don't have a total solution. I am interested in learning how to optimize just as much as I am interested in solving this particular problem, since this isn't for work or school but rather for my own edification.

Comment: It's not clear what function you're trying to write. Can you include in the question a clear description of the problem you're trying to solve? Avoid expressions like "Pavodan, with a variable lifespan" and "Pavodan generalization" and instead say explicitly what the function is. I note that the wikipedia page on Pavodan doesn't mention lifetimes or rabbits, so your terminology is confusing.

Comment: Well, one thing to keep in mind is that function calls are pretty expensive in Python, so recursion is slower than the equivalent iteration. You are calling `fib()` quite a lot. Also, you can try saving your results (also called caching or "memoizing") so that you only ever have to calculate something once, and thereafter just look it up in your saved results. The exact ways to implement this are way beyond what fits in a comment, but maybe this is enough to get you thinking about it and researching it, if you haven't already.

Comment: @PaulHankin: `Avoid expressions like "Pavodan, with a variable lifespan" and …` especially the [typo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Both your functions have exponential time complexity, so they will be very slow. You will need to find a better algorithm. While you are thinking, you might want to run this program in Python, say `fibs(50)`, and see what it does:

```
def fibs(n):
    a,b = 1,1
    while n > 0:
        print a
        a,b,n = b,a+b,n-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a rework of your code with a better recursive Fibonacci function (though not as fast as iterative) and *memoizing*, which @JohnY couldn't fit in his comment, from the blog [Memoized recursive fibonacci in Python](http://ujihisa.blogspot.com/2010/11/memoized-recursive-fibonacci-in-python.html)

The upgraded Fibonacci function alone improves the speed by about 20x.  The memoize decorator, which caches values so they don't get recomputed, improves the speed by 40x.  (My rewrite of `fibd()` makes no difference performance-wise, sigh.)

```
def memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    return lambda *args: cache[args] if args in cache else cache.update({args: f(*args)}) or cache[args]

@memoize
def fib(n, res=0, nxt=1):
    if n == 0:
        return res
    return fib(n - 1, nxt, res + nxt)

@memoize
def fibd(n, m):
    if m > 3:
        if n < (m + 2):
            return fib(n)

        return sum(map(fibd, (n - (m + x) for x in range(2 - m, 2)), [m] * m))

    elif m == 3:
        if n < (m + 1):
            return fib(n)

        return fibd(n - 2, m) + fibd(n - 3, m)

print(fibd(40, 15))
```

Overall performance went from 47 seconds to 1/20th of a second on my system.  However, I only tested the `fibd(40, 15)` case, you'll need to do more testing of this modified code.